# Can I configure a controller to reject all Post methods?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, post, asp.net-web-api2

We have a few Controllers which expect to only process GET requests.  When a POST arrives it returns a 500 and I would rather return a 405 (Method Not Allowed).  Is there a way to set this up so all the Routes on a controller return 405 when a POST is received?   Some of the controllers need to accept POST so it cant be in the IIS config (i.e configure to reject verbs).  For your information the platform is an Azure Web App.

I do have a solution which works, but has a disadvantage of having to be added to every route, which seems cumbersome.

```
    [Route("example/route/{date:datetime}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public Periods GetExampleRoute(DateTime date)
    {
        if (Request.Method.Method.Equals("POST"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
        }
        ... GET processing ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do an [MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) `ActionFilter` (similarly for [Web Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), `System.Web.Http`):

```
public class RestrictVerbsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    private string Protocol { get; }

    public RestrictVerbsAttribute(string verb)
    {
        Protocol = verb;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
        var result = request.Request.HttpMethod.Equals(Protocol, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (!result)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed); //405
        }
    }
}
```

Which you can use at `Controller` or `Action` Level

```
[RestrictVerbs("GET")]
public class VerbsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

POSTing to any Action in controller:

[image: Request inspection]

Hth...

Comment: I knew there had to be at least one way better than cut 'n' paste!  Thank-you.